# Execute jquery script after page loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I try to execute the following script, after the page was loaded.

First i included jquery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then i wrote my script:

```
<script>
    function scale()
    {
        $hc = document.getElementById("hc").innerHTML;
        $he = document.getElementById("he").innerHTML;
        $we = document.getElementById("we").innerHTML;

        jQuery('#mydiv_cam')    .css('height', '8000px');

        jQuery('#camera')       .css('height', $hc+"px");
        jQuery('#viewport')     .css('height', $he+"px");
        jQuery('#viewport')     .css('width', $we+"px");
    }
</script>
```

This is my body tag

```
<body onload="scale();">
```

And inside of the body i load the variables:

```
<p hidden="true" id="hc"> <?php echo $höhe_camera ?> </p>
<p hidden="true" id="he"> <?php echo $heightexplode[1] ?> </p>
<p hidden="true" id="we"> <?php echo $widthexplode[1] ?> </p>
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: just a note: You should never use german umlauts as variable names! `$höhe_camera`. Also mixing up multiple languages is a rather bad style, would be better if you'd stick to one, preferable english.

Comment: It is possible though, it is also possible in C++ and also do this. Why not?

Comment: Provide MCVE, your question is missing relevant info as how do you debug it? What do you mean by not working? Etc...

Comment: I said that nothing happens. What is MCVE and how can i provide it?

Comment: @EdwardBlack https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute your function on document load then just do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $hc = document.getElementById("hc").innerHTML;
    $he = document.getElementById("he").innerHTML;
    $we = document.getElementById("we").innerHTML;

    jQuery('#mydiv_cam')    .css('height', '8000px');

    jQuery('#camera')       .css('height', $hc+"px");
    jQuery('#viewport')     .css('height', $he+"px");
    jQuery('#viewport')     .css('width', $we+"px");
   //put everything else inside here
});
```

This will set this function as the ready function for the document so it will be executed as soon as the document will be fully loaded. Also you can remove the attribute on the body tag. Also, you may want to fix your jQuery import:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did this, but still nothing changes.

Comment: I solved it thx to your hint. PS: you are missing the `function() { }` Block.

Comment: @EdwardBlack You are welcome. Could you accept the answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove spaces before and after php tags. Write it is as below:

```
<p hidden="true" id="hc"><?php echo $höhe_camera ?></p>
<p hidden="true" id="he"><?php echo $heightexplode[1] ?></p>
<p hidden="true" id="we"><?php echo $widthexplode[1] ?></p>
```

This will work. As you are taking innerhtml of p tag in jquery it is accepting spaces also and after you are concatenating it with px so it will be consider as `1 px` is style sheet which won't work.
Try it.